# how can I use scaling function with using handler?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am developing kind of annotation tool, and using polygon,polyline and boundingbox.
I would like to control scaling in Polygon without using mouse event, and
I already adopted the handler like below for polygon - acturally, what I want to do is add the scaling function of the polygon in handler in the code below.

If someone knows about this, please let me know.

```
polyLinePositionHandler : function(dim,finalMatrix, object){
    var x = object.points[this.pointIndex].x - object.pathOffset.x;
    var y = object.points[this.pointIndex].y - object.pathOffset.y;
    return fabric.util.transformPoint(
        { x : x, y : y, },
        fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices( object.canvas.viewportTransform, object.calcTransformMatrix() )
    );
},

actionHandler : function(eventData, transform, x, y){
    var polyline = transform.target,
    currentControl = polyline.controls[polyline.__corner],
    mouseLocalPosition = polyline.toLocalPoint( new fabric.Point(x,y), "center", "center"),
    polygonBaseSize = polyline._getNonTransformedDimensions(),
    size = polyline._getNonTransformedDimensions(0,0),
    finalPointPosition = {
        x : (mouseLocalPosition.x * polygonBaseSize.x) / size.x + polyline.pathOffset.x,
        y : (mouseLocalPosition.y * polygonBaseSize.y) / size.y + polyline.pathOffset.y
    };
    polyline.points[currentControl.pointIndex] = finalPointPosition;
    return true;
},

anchorWrapper : function(index, fn){
    return function(eventData, transform, x, y){
        var polyline = transform.target,
        absolutePoint = fabric.util.transformPoint({
            x : polyline.points[index].x - polyline.pathOffset.x,
            y : polyline.points[index].y - polyline.pathOffset.y,
        },
        polyline.calcTransformMatrix()
        ),
        actionPerformed = fn(eventData, transform, x, y),
        newDim = polyline._setPositionDimensions({});
        var polylineBaseSize = polyline._getNonTransformedDimensions();
        newX = (polyline.points[index].x - polyline.pathOffset.x) / polylineBaseSize.x,
        newY = (polyline.points[index].y - polyline.pathOffset.y) / polylineBaseSize.y;
        polyline.setPositionByOrigin(absolutePoint, newX+0.5, newY+0.5);
        return actionPerformed;
    };
},
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve and what are the problems / errors you get? Right now the question is not really clear.

Comment: @konrad I edit my question, please see and let me know what you know. Thank you,